# Posting info on a page depending on value chosen in selectbox

Tags: php

I am working with creating an ad posting page.  I have included dependable select boxes as the category selection system. All the values are being pulled from MySQL database. The table is composed of an `id` (auto increment) bridged by `master_id` and identified by category `name`.  Every category has a subcategory. So the user is forced to pick a subcategory before being able to submit the info.  I am currently looking for ideas of how to post info that has been input by user depending on the category chosen.  I have created an individual page for each subcategory. So every time an input is submitted, I want it to display in the page accordingly. For example, if I pick category: `Books` and subcategory:`Textbooks`  then post it in textbooks.php. [Live EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/index.php)

[Table Structure](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/table.php)

[Drop down menus](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/dependable-dropdown.html)

```
<form action="" method="post">          

                <select name="category" id="category" size="7" class="updateCategory" >
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Select one:</option>
                    <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>
                        <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>

                <select name="subc1" id="subc1" size="7" class="updateCategory"
                    disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" >
                    <option value="">----</option>
                </select> 

                <select name="subc2" id="subc2" size="7" class="updateCategory"
                    disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden">
                    <option value="">----</option>
                </select>


                <select name="subc3" id="subc3" size="7" class="updateCategory"
                    disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden">
                    <option value="">----</option>
                </select>

                </br>
                 Insert your name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a shot in the dark, as the question was vaguely worded.

I think that, first, you will need to make an update to the database. You will need to create either a new table or a new column. I would personally choose the table as that provides more flexibility, like so: `id`, `category_id`, `category_page` (and you could put other columns in too). Obviously, `category_id` references back to the main table category.

Then, do a select like this:

```
SELECT [COLUMNS HERE] FROM category RIGHT JOIN category_page ON category_page.category_id = category.id
```

You now have the values you need.

Then, in your PHP, return the url to the page (if you are using JS to dynamically show the new page):

```
<option value="xyz" data-url="url-for-page.php">Category Name</option>
```